gitlab dynamic repo content
We're using gitlab repos, ci/cd, jobs, variables, etc. to build/deploy containers into our local K8s environment.  I'd like to produce repo pages that scan certain areas of the repo and report data in a dynamic fashion.  Is this possible with GitLab?  My Google-fu has been weak on trying to find an answer to this question.
In other words, does GitLab support some internal scripting language (or another mechanism) so I can build a page to do something like:  parse part of the repo for values and emit those values in a table so when a user clicks on that page, it's always accurate data relative to the data in repo?

No, not really. But you could build/update a GitLab Pages site on every push to the repo. That's about the closest thing.

Thanks.  Guess I’ll use an oob process with the api and post that as an answer.
